# How to swipe iOS emulator screen

Tags: appium-ios

As soon as I upgraded my local version of Appium, all my swipe logic stopped  working. I moved to the non deprecated API, and but I'm till not able to observe swipes. I'm pretty sure I'm just not using the coordinate system correctly but I'm not sure how. I want to swipe vertically down the screen of an iOS simulator to refresh a list view.

Any pointers on how to treat properly swipe and why, and what the mechanics of it are?

Here is my code for swiping

```
PointOption fromPoint = PointOption.point(
    topView.getLocation().x,
    topView.getLocation().y);

PointOption toPoint = PointOption.point(
    bottomView.getLocation().x,
    bottomView.getLocation().y);

new TouchAction(user.mDriver)
           .press(fromPoint) 
           .moveTo(toPoint)
           .release()
           .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my version of Appium and my Java client, but those improvements didn't fix the swiping.

Apparently, one must add a wait duration for the swipe to take place.

```
WaitOptions waitOptions = WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(500));

new TouchAction(mUser.mDriver)
        .press(fromPoint)
        .waitAction(waitOptions)
        .moveTo(toPoint)
        .release()
        .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code it is working fine for IOS simulator swiping .

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;    
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();    
scrollObject.put("direction", "left");    
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
```